# Is it necessary to have "islamic" or "muslim" in tags?

Tags: discussion

Is it necessary to have *"islamic"* ([islamic-rules](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/islamic-rules)) or "muslim" ([muslim-practices](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/muslim-practices)) in a tag?

We already have a *mega* tag on top-left corner of the site which reads *"Islam"*, so wouldn't tags like [rules](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rules) and [practices](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/practices) do?

Answer (score 2):

I definitely understand where you're coming from: I don't see that there's really any advantage to the prefix, as if the question isn't actually about "Islamic" rules or "Muslim" practices it's pretty much by definition off-topic for the site anyway.

In general, I reckon the prefix should only really be used for tags in which the "non-Islamic" form would also be a valid (and wholly different) tag.  I can, for example, easily see a [law](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/law) (or [secular-law](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/secular-law)) tag having a place on this site (despite it not actually existing yet) for questions on how to live with non-Islamic law under secular authorities, which would make it very much distinct from the existing [islamic-law](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/islamic-law).

I cannot, however, see a likely use-case for [non-islamic-rules](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/non-islamic-rules) or [non-islamic-practices](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/non-islamic-practices), so the prefix is probably unnecessary for those.

---

On the other hand, [rules](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rules) and [practices](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/practices) just look so…in need of definition.  They feel like the type of tag that just just be tacked onto *anything*, which makes them ultimately *useless* (which, admittedly, is no different from the prefixed version of the tag, it's just that dropping the prefix really makes the vagueness stand out).

So for this *specific* case, both tags appear to be in severe need of definition (or arguably deleted), regardless of if they're prefixed or not.